# While trying to compute minimum monthly payments, my keeps returning values that are a bit too high

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

While trying to compute minimum monthly payments, my keeps returning values that are a bit too high. I need to use a binary search to complete the problem, but it makes so much more sense to me to just compute it using formulas used in finance.

This is what I wrote:

```
balance = 101 
annualInterestRate = 0.2

MIR = (annualInterestRate/12)+1
minpmt = balance/12
maxpmt =( balance*(MIR)**12)/12
pmt = ((minpmt+maxpmt)/2)

while balance>= float(.01):
    for month in range (0,12):
        balance =-pmt
        balance = balance*MIR
    if balance < 0:
        maxpmt = pmt
    if balance >0:
        minpmt = pmt
    pmt = ((minpmt+maxpmt)/2)

print("Lowest Payment: " + str(round(pmt,2)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: What output do you see, and what is the output you expect?  *Why* do you have to use binary search when you have a direct "closed-form" formula?  If the balance is finally zero, how do you conclude that the printed payment is a bit too high?

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting will help here. Sprinkle some print statements through your code so you can monitor the variables and follow the flow. Note where you see the first unexpected value and you'll have a better idea where to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Your largest problem is that you quit at the first payment amount that pays off the loan in time: I think you need to get close, not simply pay enough.

```
while abs(balance) >= float(.01):
```

Next, you forgot to reset your loan amount on each iteration.  Given a reasonable first approximation, you'll never do more than two guesses at the payment: your balance for the second guess starts at the *ending* balance form the first guess.  You have to reset it on each computation.

However, your most significant error is a typo in deducting the month's payment:

```
balance =-pmt     # You set balance to the negative of the payment.  OOPS!
```

Try a decrement instead:

```
balance -= pmt
```